# Can you splat positional arguments in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

Does PowerShell support splatting of positional arguments as opposed to named parameters?

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: Writing a script and building command parameters. Wanted to avoid the use of `Invoke-Command`, realized I have some positional parameters that aren't named (not prefixed with a `-`, anyways).

Comment: I believe my answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472772 should work for you (you can ignore the downvote).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PowerShell's **argument splatting** (see [`Get-Help about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)) offers two fundamental choices:

- **splatting via a *hashtable***: works for ***named* arguments *only*** (e.g., `-Path C:\Windows`
- **splatting via an *array*-like value**: works for ***positional* arguments *only*** (e.g., `C:\Windows`) - *except* in *non-advanced* functions that pass *all* [unbound] arguments through *to another command* via `@args` (i.e., by splatting the [automatic `$args` array variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) containing all unbound arguments), in which case named arguments are also supported, owing to magic built into `@args` only.

Note: This dichotomy applies when passing arguments to *PowerShell* cmdlets / functions (with declared parameters), whereas *external programs* perform their own argument parsing, which may or may not interpret the set of arguments passed as named.<sup>[1]</sup>

That said, **you can *combine* either form with regular, individual argument passing** - using any combination of individual positional arguments, individual named arguments, hashtable-splatting, and array-splatting.

In both cases, the source data structure must be:

- *stored* in a variable beforehand.
- *referenced* with **sigil `@`** instead of `$`.

Note: A future enhancement, detailed in this [RFC](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/blob/master/2-Draft-Accepted/RFC0002-Generalized-Splatting.md), may bring the ability to splat expressions directly, without the need for an intermediate variable, though as of PowerShell Core 7 it is unclear when this will be implemented.

---

**Examples**:

```
# Positional binding via *array*. 
# Note that a function's / script block's parameters are by default positional.
PS> $posArgs = 'one', 'two'; & { param($foo, $bar) "`$foo: $foo"; "`$bar: $bar" } @posArgs
$foo: one
$bar: two


# Named binding via *hashtable*
PS> $namedArgs=@{bar='two';foo='one'}; & { param($foo, $bar) "`$foo: $foo"; "`$bar: $bar" } @namedArgs
$foo: one
$bar: two

# *Combining* hashtable splatting with a regular, positional argument
PS> $namedArgs=@{bar='two'}; & { param($foo, $bar) "`$foo: $foo"; "`$bar: $bar" } @namedArgs one
$foo: one
$bar: two
```

---

[1] Splatting with **external programs**:

Generally, you do *not* need splatting when you call external programs, because:

- You can pass *arrays as-is* (with the usual `$` sigil)

  - The only exception is if you wanted to include `%--`, the stop-parsing symbol (see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), in the array of arguments; you do need to use the `@` sigil in that event.
  - Use the individual array elements to satisfy the external program's syntax requirements, including its named arguments, if any
    (e.g., `$args = '/c', 'ver'; cmd $args` to execute `cmd /c ver`).
- The way *hashtable splats* are translated into command-line tokens may or may not be recognized by external programs:

  - Specifically, a hashtable entry with key `<paramName>` and value `<value>` is translated into a *single* argument formatted as `-<paramName>:<value>` - a format that few external command-line utilities recognize.