# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 't'

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

I am getting the following error

```
New-AzResourceGroup : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 't'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroup -Name @rgName -Location @location -Tag @{LoB="pla ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzResourceGroup], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGrou
pCmdlet
```

while trying to create a new resource group with the following code. Where is the issue?

```
$rgName = "storage-dev-rg"
$location = "eastus"
New-AzResourceGroup -Name @rgName -Location @location -Tag @{LoB="platform"; CostCenter="IT"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57536954/45375):

> The declared variables should be referenced using `$`, not with `@`.

[about_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables) explains that in order **to create and later reference variables in PowerShell, you prefix their name with sigil `$` in both cases**; i.e., `$rgName` and `$location` in your case.

**You only ever prefix a variable name with sigil `@` if you want to perform *splatting*** (see [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)).

(The sigil `@` has other uses too, namely as `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator, and as `@{ ... }`, a hashtable *literal*, as also used in your command.)

Splatting is used to pass an array-like value stored in a variable as individual positional arguments or, more typically, to bind the entries of a hashtable containing parameter name-value pairs to the parameters so named - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219535/45375).

Since your variables contain *strings* and strings can be treated as an *array-like collection of characters* (via the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface), **splatting a *string* variable effectively passes each character as a separate, positional argument**.

```
PS> $foo = 'bar'; Write-Output @foo # same as: Write-Output 'b' 'a' 'r'
b
a
r
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`-Name @rgName`, based on `$rgName` containing string `'storage-dev-rg'`, passed `'s'` - the 1st char only - to `-Name`, and the remaining characters as individual, positional arguments. `'t'`, the 2nd character, was the first such positional argument, and since `New-AzResourceGroup` didn't expect any *positional* arguments, it complained about it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The declared variables should be referenced using `$`, not with `@`.