# How to pass a switch parameter as a variable / via splatting in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, variables, switch-parameter, parameter-splatting

If you have multiple parameters which require a value when calling a command or a script, I know you can pass it like this:

```
$parameters = @{
    name = "John"
    last_name = "Doe"
}
```

But if the command or script actually just expect `-T` to indicate something like a flag, but the parameter itself doesn't require a value. How can I set that in a variable?

```
$optionalT = ""
if ($itNeedsTheT) $optionalT = "-T"

command $optionalT
```

If I do it like that it complains with the following message:

```
Unknown argument 'T' on command line.
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you are asking, but if you want to know how to [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) a switch parameter, then you can just set it to `$true`/`$false` in the hashtable.  For example: `@{NormalParam = 'Value'; SwitchParam = $true}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```bash
# Pass the $itNeedsTheT Boolean - which indicates whether the -T switch should
# be passed - as the switch's *value*.
command -T:$itNeedsTheT
```

If `$itNeedsTheT` is `$false`, the above is the same as *omitting* `-T` - *usually* (read on for details).

Note the need to use `:` to separate the switch name from the value.

---

As [boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog) points out in a comment, in a hashtable used with [splatting (`@parameters`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219535/45375), you **use a *Boolean* value to represent a switch parameter** (a flag-like parameter of type `[switch]`) .

```bash
# Dynamically determine if -Recurse should be turned on.
$recurseIfTrue = $true

# Define the hashtable for splatting...
$parameters = @{
  Path = '.'
  Recurse = $recurseIfTrue  # turn the -Recurse switch on or off
}

# ... and pass it to the target command.
# *Loosely speaking*, the following command is the same as either:
#   Get-ChildItem -Path '.' -Recurse  # if $recuseIfTrue was $true
# or:
#   Get-ChildItem -Path '.'           # if $recuseIfTrue was $false
Get-ChildItem @parameters
```

That is, loosely speaking:

- use `$true` to *pass* the switch
- use `$false` to *not* pass the switch.

This allows you to keep a single hashtable definition that unconditionally includes the switch parameter, but whose value can determine programmaticaly.

**Caveat**:

Strictly speaking, hashtable entry **`Recurse = $true`** translates to parameter **`-Recurse:$true`** and **`Recurse = $false`** doesn't translate into *omitting* the parameter, it translates to passing **`-Recurse:$false`**.

**In *most* cases, *omitting* a switch `-Foo` and passing it with value `$false` - i.e. `-Foo:$false` - are *equivalent*.**

**However, commands *can* detect the difference and sometimes *act differently*:**

A notable example is the `-Confirm` common (switch) parameter: *omitting* `-Confirm` means that the `$ConfirmPreference` preference variable is respected, whereas `-Confirm:$false` means that the preference variable should be *overridden* (and confirmation should *not* be requested).

If you want to make this distinction yourself in a PowerShell script or function, you can call `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Foo')` in addition to checking the `$Foo` (`-Foo`) switch parameter variable's value.

If you're dealing with such a command and you want to programmatically enforce *omission* of a switch parameter, you'll have no choice but to *conditionally* add an entry for this switch, in a separate step:

```bash
# Dynamically determine if -Recurse should be turned on.
$recurseIfTrue = $true

# A 'Recurse' key now can NOT be included unconditionally,
# if you want to *omit* -Recurse in case $recurseIfTrue is $false
$parameters = @{
  Path = '.'
}

# Add a 'Recurse' entry only if the switch should be passed.
if ($recurseIfTrue) {
  $parameters.Recurse = $true
}

Get-ChildItem @parameters
```

---

Finally, note that as an alternative to specifying a switch value programmatically via splatting, **you can pass a dynamic value to a switch directly**:

```bash
# Dynamically determine if -Recurse should be turned on.
$recurseIfTrue = $true

Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse:$recurseIfTrue
```

Note the **need to use `:` to separate the switch name from its value**.

This is necessary, because using the customary *whitespace* to separate the parameter name from its value would cause PowerShell to interpret the Boolean as the *next* argument, given that switch parameters normally do not take *values*.

Although rarely used, this `:`-based syntax works with *all* parameter types.

Comment: This is an amazingly rich answer. Thanks a million for being so elaborate. In my own case, I have always struggled with having to make verbose duplications to append dynamic switch conditions. Never knew about the `-Foo:$Bar` option!

Answer (score 5):

When splatting, create the hashtable with non-conditional parameters (the values can be variable), but add the optional parameters after the hashtable is created:

```
$parameters = @{
  Name = "John"
  LastName = "Doe"
  Age = $age
  Enabled = $true
}

if( $favoriteThing ){
  $parameters.FavoriteThing = $favoriteThing
}

command @parameters
```

If dealing with a switch in splatting, you can treat it as a boolean parameter like shown above, just give it a value of `$true` or `$false` depending on whether you want the switch to be enabled on the command or not. You can see a non-splat example of this to set a `-Confirm` flag to `$false`:

```
Install-Package some_package -Confirm:$false
```