# Powershell Dynamic Parameters Not Working With Switch

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a script going that installs an application and sets up the scheduled task. The problem is that I am not able to pass the dynamic values into the `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`

```
$triggerParams = @{
    Once=$false
    Daily=$false
    Weekly=$true
    At="12AM"
}

New-ScheduledTaskTrigger $triggerParams
```

Getting this error with my simple test above.

```
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Once'. Cannot convert value "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter". Boolean parameters accept only  Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0. At D:\Code\test.ps1:9 char:26
+ New-ScheduledTaskTrigger $triggerParams
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,New-ScheduledTaskTrigger
```

It looks like it should work based on this question: [How to pass a switch parameter as a variable / via splatting in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507217/how-to-pass-a-switch-parameter-as-a-variable-via-splatting-in-powershell)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for splatting is

```
New-ScheduledTaskTrigger @triggerParams
```

So, use a `@` character on splatting instead of the `$` you need when defining the hashtable.

Comment: .... well I feel like a moron. lol. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was declaring the splat object as a `PSCustomObject` instead of a regular hashtable.