# Powershell looping Test-NetConnection

Tags: powershell

I'm a bit new to Powershell scripting and I'm trying to create a simple loop with the `Test-NetConnection` tool, but I don't know how to do this.

This is what I have:

```
param(
  [string]$tcpserveraddress,
  [string]$tcpport
)
if (Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $tcpserveraddress -Port $tcpport -InformationLevel Quiet -WarningAction SilentlyContinue) {"Port $tcpport is open" }
else {"Port $tcpport is closed"}
```

- If the tcpport is *not* open, I would like the script to loop and issue the text "Port $tcpport is closed" every 10 seconds, until it is open.
- When tcppport *is* open, it should display the "Port $tcpport is open" text and terminate.

Comment: `while( ! (Test-NetConnection ...)) {"Port $tcpport is closed"; Start-Sleep 10}`

Comment: Hi zett42,
Thank you very much for your fast help. This is working great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `while` loop to achieve this with a few modifications to your existing code:

```
param(
  [string]$tcpserveraddress,
  [string]$tcpport
)

$tcnArgs = @{
  ComputerName = $tcpserveraddress
  Port = $tcpport
  WarningAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
}

while( !( Test-NetConnection @tcnArgs ).TcpTestSucceeded ) {
  "Port $tcpport is closed"
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}

"Port $tcpport is open"
```

Since you indicated you are new to PowerShell, here's a breakdown of how this works:

- For the sake of readability, I have use **argument splatting** to define and pass the cmdlet parameters as a hashmap. Here are some [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51219535/584676) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485284/584676) that explain splatting in more detail, for those interested.
- No longer use `-InformationLevel Quiet`. In a script we generally want the detailed object as it has more information on it, and we can operate off of its properties.
- The `while` loops, until `( Test-NetConnection @tcnArgs ).TcpTestSucceeded` returns true. In other words, the loop code runs while the TCP test is failing.
- Sleep in the loop, no need to check constantly.
- Once the `while` loop exits, output a string stating the TCP port is open